# connceting Socket IO inside Websocket server python

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

I am having a config server which will be communicated with Socket IO and emitter server which will be communicated using WebSocket. Now client request data to Emitter Server, emitter server will communicate with config server as per the client request. I am facing a issue in connecting with Socket IO inside the Websocket connect. It is failing because of wait timeout in Socket IO. How to make the websocket to wait for the response

```
async def connect(websocket):
"""Event handler for websocket server
Args:
    websocket
"""
global M_CONNECTED_CLIENTS
#message_json=''
M_CONNECTED_CLIENTS.add(websocket)
try:
    async for message in websocket:
        message_json = json.loads(message)
        if message_json["PATH"]=="getdata":
            response="I am sendding the data"
            _connect_to_config_server()
            response =M_CONFIG_SIO_CLIENT.call("getdata", {})
        else:
            response=message["PATH"]+" is not defined."
        await websocket.send(message)
        await websocket.wait_closed()
except Exception as error:
    print("An exception occurred",error)
finally:
    M_CONNECTED_CLIENTS.remove(websocket)

def _connect_to_config_server():
"""Connection to configuration Server
    Required for accessing flex credentials and user roles
"""
try:
    if not M_CONFIG_SIO_CLIENT.connected:
        token_role = _get_access_token("system")
        print("before Connecting to the server")
        M_CONFIG_SIO_CLIENT.connect(M_CONFIG_DATA.config_server_add,
                                    headers = {'AUTHORIZATION': token_role["Access_token"]},
                                    wait_timeout = 100000)
        print("Connected to server")
except Exception as ex:
    print("An exception occurred", ex)
```